# django-templatetag-handlebars - declare repeated template code once

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, handlebars.js

I am using django 1.7 & python 2.7. It is all still quite new to me so I am still learning.

I am also using [django-templatetag-handlebars](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-templatetag-handlebars) in my templates.

I have a dynamic template that uses the same template code several times in the same template.

**How do I declare the repeated code once and then reference it where I need it? [Handlebars.js uses partials](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html), but I am not so sure how I can use [partials](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html) in the [django-templatetag-handlebars](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-templatetag-handlebars).**

Here is my template code:

```
{% load templatetag_handlebars %}

{% tplhandlebars "address_details_live_preview_template_ltr" %}
   ....
   {{# if address_style_01 }}

        {{! Address Style: 1 }}

        {{# if address_line_1 }}
            {{ address_line_1 }}<span class="spacer"></span>
        {{/if}}
        {{# if address_street_details }}
            {{ address_street_details }}<span class="spacer"></span>
        {{/if}}
        {{# if address_locality }}
            {{ address_locality }}<span class="spacer"></span>
        {{/if}}
        {{# if address_country_name }}
            {{ address_country_name }}
        {{/if}}

    {{else}}
    ....
```

Comment: Why not use default [include mecanism](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-include) of django template?

Comment: felipsmartins, see comment in your response below.

Comment: felipsmartins deleted his answer that incorrectly suggested that the django include tag be used to solve this issue. felipsmartins deleted the answer b/c it is not possible to use the include tag inside a `{% tplhandlebars "" %}` tag, which is what I referred to in the comment above.